# Realm doesn't write the data in IntentService

Tags: android, realm, intentservice

I  have the  Realm database in my app. When my app is active I have no problem with  writing the data but if I start IntentService and then close the app,  I have nothing in Realm database.

My IntentService:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

            RealmResults<HashtagObject> hashtags;
            SubscriberObject subscriber = new SubscriberObject();

            Realm realmForThisThread = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            hashtags = realmForThisThread.where(HashtagObject.class).findAll();

           for(int i=0;i<hashtags.size();i++){
                getRecentlyTag(Constants.API_URL);
            }
            realmForThisThread.beginTransaction();

            for (Map.Entry entry : hm.entrySet()) {
                if(realmForThisThread.where(SubscriberObject.class)
                        .equalTo(SubscriberObject.ID,entry.getKey().toString()).findAll().isEmpty()) {
                    subscriber.setId(entry.getKey().toString());
                    subscriber.setUsername(entry.getValue().toString());
                    subscriber.setDate(mDate.getTime());
                    realmForThisThread.insert(subscriber);
                }
            }
            realmForThisThread.commitTransaction();
            realmForThisThread.close();
}
```

private void getRecentlyTag(String path,final String tagName){

```
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                URL url = new URL(path);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.connect();
                String response = Tools.streamToString(urlConnection
                        .getInputStream());
                JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response)
                        .nextValue();
                for(int i=0;i<jsonObj.getJSONArray("data").length();i++) {
                    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) jsonObj.getJSONArray("data").get(i);
                   hm.put(json.getJSONObject("user").getString("id"),json.getJSONObject("user").getString("username"));
                }

            }catch(Exception exc){
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                if(urlConnection!=null){
                    try{
                        urlConnection.disconnect();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

I am using:

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.0.2" // Top-level build file
compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.3.0' //app gradle
```

Starts the IntentService in the Fragment like:

```
    @OnClick(R.id.find_users)
    public void startClick(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SubscribersGathering.class);
        getActivity().startService(intent);
    }
```

Realm cofigs in Application class:

```
    Realm.init(this);
    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
```

Comment: Maybe your `IntentService` stops whenever the app is closed

Comment: No, I have only start code: Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SubscribersGathering.class); getActivity().startService(intent);

Comment: In order to run a service in the background you need to declare it in your manifest, take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)

Comment: I declared and the IntentService work and writing into Realm when my app  is working. But if I closed the app (when IntentService is working) the data doesn't write into Realm.

Comment: Which version of Realm are you using?

Comment: Why are you using raw `HttpUrlConnection` instead of Retrofit (or Volley)?

Comment: @josemigallas Version - classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.0.2", compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.3.0'

Comment: @ EpicPandaForce it's  difficult question) At the beginning I did so, but then I plan to recreate some part of the app. Also, using of additional libraries are not very good, there are some errors ccan be (for  example MultiDex)

Comment: I'd suggest you share the code of the **IntentService** class, **build.gradle** files, **Manifest** and the **Activity** or component where you start the service, then we can help you better

Comment: @josemigallas I added more information but I think it's a problem  with Realm working and Android lifecycle.